# How to not match text if it is followed by a specific text?

Tags: python, regex

https://regex101.com/r/jiRO1M/1

Pattern: `A.*?D(?!toA.*?D)`

Here is the text

```
AzzDtoAxxD
AvvD
AnnD
```

I want to match `AvvD` and `AnnD` only

Comment: `AzzDtoAxxD` is not followed by `toAxxD`, that's why it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple exotic ways to solve this.
Depends on what your dependency is.

This method insures not a pair of `A.*?D` separated by a `to`.

```
(?m)^(?!.*?A.*?DtoA.*?D).*?(A.*?D)
```

https://regex101.com/r/HeH2bD/1

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 (?! .*? A .*? DtoA .*? D )
 .*? 
 ( A .*? D )                   # (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
\bA[^AD]*D\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6BPQ1B/3).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A                        'A'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^AD]*                   any character except: 'A', 'D' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  D                        'D'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

OR:

```py
\bA[^AD]*D(?!toA.*D)
```

See [this regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6BPQ1B/4).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A                        'A'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^AD]*                   any character except: 'A', 'D' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  D                        'D'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    toA                      'toA'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    D                        'D'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```